# zend link button element in controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this button in my controller and trying to echo it back to the user in my view phtml but its seems not to be returning the element.

Button

```
    $button = new Zend_Form_Element_button('button');
    $button->setAttrib('id', 'B!');
    $button->setLabel('Previous');
    $button->setAttrib('onClick', "parent.location='" . Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl() .'/../..' ."'");

$this->view->button = $button;
```

in my view

```
<?php echo $this->button; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code work in my application.

If you just want a button, you can do something like that:

In your Controller :

```
$this->view->location = "parent.location='" . Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl() .'/../..' . "'";
```

In the view

```
<input id="B" type="button" value="Previous" onClick="<?php echo $this->location;?>">
```

Comment: The url is not the problem the button is, its not visible to the user the is some echoing problems

Comment: Ohk I will re check it

Comment: The on click is not working this way its not redirecting back

Comment: Got it working just needed to re-position the code in my controller